# OleDbPermission in .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, permissions

I have a windows program in .net framework 3.5 to update an access database, I need to set the permission to full trust level. the client don't have the framework configuration tools installed on their server, so is there any other place that I can make this change?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the trust levels with the notepad:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx